# Keep div inside view port or arbitrary div on scrolling

Tags: javascript, css, prototypejs, scriptaculous

I'm trying to find a scriptaculous script (or create one) which keeps a vertical navigation bar "sticky" inside my viewport. While this may not be black magic (one could use the position:fixed css) there is a problem with this approach: If the navigation bar is longer than the viewport height the visitor won't be able to ever see the whole navigation. So I want that the navigation bar to not leave the viewport at its top but neither leave the parent container at its bottom. It should follow scroll events instantly without fancy/bouncing animations.

Is that possible? Google revealed nothing useful to me. You may know this kind of effect from slashdot's article comment navigator or google video's player box.

**Update:** Essentially that would be a rewrite of the jQuery plugin [scrollFollow](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-scroll-follow/source/browse/trunk/lib/jquery.scrollfollow.js). It would be no problem if it lacked animations as I won't use them. But it should be able to stay within a defined parent container without clipping. The cookie handling is neither needed.

Comment: Can you link an example? I have difficulty drawing an image in my mind.

Comment: Here is the example from slashdot, apparently only showing the "do not scroll off the top" feature: http://science.slashdot.org/story/09/11/28/1812203/Tapering-Waveguide-Captures-a-Rainbow

But having this with scriptaculous would be a starting point for me to extent it with my other requirement.

Answer (score 8):

I know this is really old but stumbled across this whilst trying to find my own solution

This [link](http://css-tricks.com/scrollfollow-sidebar/) shows how to do it in a really lightweight fashion.  Essentially all you need is the following code (along with jQuery loaded of course)

```
$(function() {
    var $sidebar   = $("#siderbar"),
        $window    = $(window),
        offset     = $sidebar.offset(),
        topPadding = 15;

    $window.scroll(function() {
        if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top) {
            $sidebar.stop().animate({
                marginTop: $window.scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
            });
        } else {
            $sidebar.stop().animate({
                marginTop: 0
            });
        }
    });
})
```

If you don't want it to animate simply replace the animation sections like so:

```
$sidebar.stop().animate({ marginTop: VALUE });
```

with

```
$sidebar.css("marginTop", VALUE);
```

Comment: Oh, thanx, this is still an open issue for me. I've thought of a scroll-event-and-reposition solution, too. But I think it will become more smooth if you change CSS attributes in a way to make the browser stick the element relative to the view port OR relative to the document, this should eliminate flicker/jitter/skew which I've seen with many solutions. But your code is a good starting point, so +1.

Comment: When I use this to scroll Google Maps inside a DIV I get no flicker or lag! I've noticed borders on elements seem to provide most of the flicker

Comment: Simple. Effective. Awesome.  This way does not use strange positioning techniques and keeps the element inside its parent. +1

Answer (score 3):

I know this issue is old but it came up in my Google search for making a div stay on the page for scrolling. This solution works quite well and didn't allow the page to have an infinite scroll in my situation like the solution from @Chris above.

It requires adding an empty div `<div id="sticky-anchor"></div>`  above the floating div to serve as an anchor.

In this example, the div needs to have `id="sticky"`

Solution: **http://blog.yjl.im/2010/01/stick-div-at-top-after-scrolling.html**

Javascript:

```
function sticky_relocate() {
    var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
    var div_top = $('#sticky-anchor').offset().top;
    if (window_top > div_top) {
        $('#sticky').addClass('stick');
    } else {
        $('#sticky').removeClass('stick');
    }
}

$(function () {
    $(window).scroll(sticky_relocate);
    sticky_relocate();
});
```

CSS:

```
#sticky.stick {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10000;
}
```